# How to find multiple modes in an array

Tags: matlab, mode

I have an array [1 1 1 2 3 4 5] for which the mode is 1. However, in the array [1 1 2 2 3 4 5] there is no mode since the number of 1's and 2's is equal.

Is there a way to say that both are the modes using Matlab? Such that for the first example the mode is 1, but for the second example the modes are 1 and 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the third output of [`mode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mode.html) does:

```
>> [~,~,C] = mode([1 1 2 2 3 4 5])
C =
{
  [1,1] =

     1
     2

}
```